# I have enough memory but mmap keeps failing saying Cannot allocate memory

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am trying to `mmap` some large files but failed : I can't mmap any file that's larger than around 2.7 GB.

By doing `ulimit -a`, it says my virtual memory is unlimited. I then did `cat /proc/meminfo` it says my system has 3GB Memfree and 2GB Swapfree.

I am assuming I could mmap a file up to 5GB. I tried everything I learned on the internet, including using `MAP_NORESERVE` flag and set `overcommit_memory` to `1`. It's still the same, `Cannot allocate memory`. What could possibly go wrong?

I am using 64 bit cpu and a 32 bit linux system. Please let me know if you need anymore information. I would really appreciate any advice or tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application simply doesn't have enough address space (useable memory addresses) to map a file that large.

Under Linux, a 32 bit process running on a 32 bit kernel typically has around 3GB of address space available, and a 32 bit process running on a 64 bit kernel has 4GB of address space available.  If you need more than that, you will need to compile your application as a 64 bit process.  This will give you at least 128TB of address space.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use 64 bit OS, because 32bit os does not have enough address space.
Edit: Although your system has some physical memory available, but a 32 bit process only address up to 4GB, kernel reserve about 1-2GB for kernel driver..., so user space usually has 2GB for 32 bit applications.

Comment: If the kernel and userspace are 32-bit, 3GB is available to userspace, but it will be somewhat fragmented and the largest contiguous availability will likely be 2.5GB or less. Also it's possible that the implementation forbids (this would be smart) individual allocations > 2GB since they would result in dangerous signed integer overflows in pointer subtraction. If the kernel is 64-bit but the userspace is 32-bit, then the full 32-bit (4GB) address space should be available to userspace apps, but again it might be fragmented or have restrictions on contiguous allocations...